# How to pass values from HTML fields to component ts

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

I'm sending values from the HTML page into TS component without using form, I got an a build error when I try npm run build, here is my sample:

I have no problem using >npm run dev or >ng build
But when I build it for production, it will through an error using

> npm run build
>
> src\app\messages\messages-new\messages-new.component.html(52,22): : Property 'messageTitle' does not exist on type 'MessagesNewComponent'.

HTML:

```
<input matInput placeholder="Type a title" name="messageTitle" [(ngModel)]="messageTitle">


<button class="simple-form-button" color="primary" mat-raised-button type="submit"  value="submit" (click)="sendMessage(messageTitle)">
      <mat-icon>send</mat-icon> Send 
    </button>
```

Comment: <input matInput placeholder="Type a title" name="messageTitle" [(ngModel)]="messageTitle">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which means you need to declare the variable in your component.ts

```
messageTitle : string;
```

Comment: So what is the difference between npm run build and ng build

Comment: differentce between what?

Comment: Declaring messageTitle in the component fixed the problem, but what if I want to pass list of params into component, do I have to define it first to bind it after?

Comment: In dev mode template compiled to class in browser Just In Time. In prod mode node try to compile template to class and typescript compilation can't find the nessesary property

Comment: yes you need to define those variables whatever you are using in the HTML.